# How can i login to Azure with username and password and set subscription using c#?

Tags: c#

I currently login and set subscription using Powershell, but i need to do it using c# .
How can i do this ?

```
   $uname = "<uname>"
   $pwd ="<pwd>"
   az login -u "$uname" -p "$pwd"
   az account set --subscription "MyTestSubscription"
```

Comment: That doesn't look like C#, may I ask what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Ok let me re-phrase, I want to convert the Powershell to c#. I want to be able to login to Azure , either using app registration with clientid , secret  or user name and password and set the subscription , then get back a token to make rest api calls with ?

Comment: Are you hacking something together? or do you need an enterprise solution with managed identity?

Comment: "Set Subscription" is only useful for setting the default subscription for future commands. Do you know about the [Azure SDK for .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/azure-sdk-for-dotnet)?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is a hacky solution

To login to Azure and set a subscription using C#, you would typically use the Azure SDK. Here's how you can do this:

Setup:

- Create a new .NET Console application.
- Install the required package:

```bash
dotnet add package Azure.Identity
dotnet add package Azure.ResourceManager.Resources
```

**Use `InteractiveBrowserCredential` to authenticate and fetch subscriptions**:

```cs
using System;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;

namespace AzureInteractiveLoginDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Use InteractiveBrowserCredential for authentication
            var credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential();

            // Create a subscription client using the authenticated credential
            var subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(credential);

            // Fetch and display the list of subscriptions for the authenticated account
            Console.WriteLine("Subscriptions:");
            foreach (var sub in subscriptionClient.List())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"- ID: {sub.SubscriptionId}, Name: {sub.Name}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this application, a browser window will pop up and ask you to log in to your Azure account. Once you've authenticated, the application will list the subscriptions associated with your account.

Remember to ensure you have registered your application in the Azure Active Directory and granted the necessary permissions to access subscription information.

Also, while `InteractiveBrowserCredential` is great for local development, testing, or tools, it's not suitable for background tasks or deployed services, as it requires a user to manually authenticate. For those scenarios, consider using other methods like `ClientSecretCredential`, `ClientCertificateCredential`, or managed identities.

Comment: I installed Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus with package manager.  Cant compile gives errors:   SubscriptionClient does not contain a constructor   that takes one argument and SubscriptionClient does not contain a definition of List ?

Comment: I need to be able to login to Azure from c# and perform some tasks . I want to make some rest calls .. like the following :   GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/instances/{instanceId}?api-version=2022-03-01